# C++ Operator Overloading '+'

Tags: c++

I have encountered a problem when trying to overload the '+' operator to add two Money objects rands and cents.

### The error:

I encountered on the console is " 'Money Money::operator+(Money*, Money*)' must take either zero or one argument".

### My resolution:

1) I tried to use the two integer values 'rands' and 'cents' in my class to store the result when adding the two money.

2) I also researched another way which was to only pass one object to the function (it seemed to work by not producing the same error, but I had to implement a getMoney() method to recieve the rands and cents individually...)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Money{
public:
    int rands;
    int cents;

    Money();
    Money(int rands,int cents);
    Money operator+(Money* obj,Money* obj2){return obj};
};

  Money::Money(){
    rands = 0;
    cents = 0;
}

  Money::Money(int randsN, int centsN){
    rands = randsN;
    cents = centsN;
}

 Money Money::operator+(Money *obj , Money *obj2){
    obj.rands += obj2.rands;
    obj.cents += obj2.cents;

    return obj;
}

int main(){
    Money totalCash=Money();

    Money cash = Money(200,20);
    Money cashTwo = Money(100,10);

    totalCash = cash + cashTwo;
}
```

---

```
1) FIXES: (Working code)
=========================

//Struct Money

    struct Money{
        int rands;
        int cents;

public:
    Money();
    Money(int rands,int cents);
    Money operator+(const Money&)const; // changed
};

// Operator Overload '+' : Working for adding two Money objects

     Money Money::operator+(const Money &obj)const{
         int totRands=0;
         int totCents=0;

         totRands= obj.rands + rands;
         totCents= obj.cents + cents;

         Money newMoney= Money(totRands,totCents);

        return newMoney;
    }
```

---

Thank you Stackoverflow community.

Comment: Why is your code using `Money*` pointers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/635608

Comment: Remove obj from your argument list and replace obj in the function definition with *this . Member +operator overload takes exactly one argument. The second operand is the caller object, i.e. "this".

Comment: `Money Money::operator+(const Money& obj) {Money result(rand + obj.rand, cents + obj.cents); return result;}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operator+ function should have the following signature if you want to use a claa member operator+:

```
Money operator+( const Money& ) const;
```

Or you may also define it as not member of the class:

```
Money operator+( const Money&, const Money& );
```

Comment: I tried the first declaration (it works). Although when I try the second declaration (my code yields the same error as before?). I am currently trying to understand why this is so, my build options is for C11. Might that be causing me problems?

Comment: @Sherenica: Where did you put the declaration ? The second declaration should be put outside the Money class. There's nothing related to C++11 here.

Comment: I placed the declaration within the class. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator can be used as a unary operator or a binary operator.

Both of them can be overloaded as either member functions or non-member functions.

When the unary opertor is overloaded a member function, it has to be of the form:

```
Money operator+() const;
```

When the unary opertor is overloaded as a non-member function, it has to be of the form:

```
Money operator+(Money const&);
```

When the binary opertor is overloaded a member function, it has to be of the form:

```
Money operator+(Money const& rhs) const;
```

When the binary opertor is overloaded as a non-member function, it has to be of the form:

```
Mone operator+(Money const& lhs, Money const& rhs);
```

Your declaration does not fit any of the above synactic forms. Hence, it is an error.

Further reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators.

Answer (score 0):

`Money::operator+` is a member function. It should be declared like:

```
Money operator+(const Money &obj) const;
```

Comment: why the first const?

Comment: @jakub_d as Scott Meyers notes in [Effective C++](https://www.amazon.com/Effective-Specific-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/0321334876), such operators should return `const` values to be consistent with built-in types, otherwise you could do things like `money1 + money2 = money3` which would be invalid with built-in types

Comment: you can't do that anyway, Money is not an lvalue; also obj should be const

Comment: @Ayxan I wonder if that was written in pre-C++11 days. Since C++11 that's a terrible advice, as `const` inhibits moving from the returned object (it doesn't matter in OP's case, but is important in general case). If you want to prevent `operator=` calls on rvalues, there is no need to put `const` everywhere. Simply lvalue-ref-qualify the `operator=` like so: `Money &operator=(const Money &) & = default;`!

Comment: @jakub_d You can assign to class rvalues, unless you specifically prevent it, e.g. by lvalue-ref-qualifying `operator=`.

Comment: @jakub_d see [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6EitegSKdHKn6My2)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, it is pre-C++11, thanks for pointing out. I'll edit the answer accordingly